# Schema for setting up a monthly subscription

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, schema, e-commerce, subscription

I have an app which lists venues. Each venue can be either free or premium and so have different privileges. I would like to be able to link the premium upgrade to a payment but am struggling with how to do it.

Im pretty sure I'll end up using chargify or spreedly for the payments but what should the schema look like?

I'm thinking a monthly subscription would be best so should I set up another table of subscriptions and have a record generated each time a subscription is created or amended? So a venue would have many subscriptions and would it be sensible for each subscription record to have a boolean expired field with switches 28 days after it is generated?.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Use Stripe. It integrates very well with Rails and has incredible (and sensible) documentation. Ryan Bates also did an excellent RailsCast on integrating Stripe with Rails, and his example is for a monthly subscription so you should be able to just follow along.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/288-billing-with-stripe

Answer (score 0):

In the [SaaS Rails Kit](http://railskits.com/saas/) here's what I have:

Account (loaded by subdomain) has_one Subscription
Subscription has a datetime field, next_renewal_at, which gets set a month ahead every time billing happens successfully.
SubscriptionPayment (belongs_to Subscription) gets created every time a successful billing happens.

I don't know why your Venue would have many Subscriptions, but basically in my approach each Subscription has a billing token (provided by Stripe) that is used for charging a credit card.